# Aggregating value from java ArrayList in an elegant way

Tags: java

I have a list of objects which I want to aggregate one of the values of this object grouped by other values of the objects in this list.

I'm currently using the properties I want to group by as a Hash key and I'm traversing the object so:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> raw = Some Data;
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

for (MyObject ungrouped : raw) {
  String key = ungrouped.getStringOne().getName() + ungrouped.getStringTwo() + ungrouped.getStringThree();

  if (map.containsKey(key)){
    MyObject holder = map.get(key);
    holder.setNumericProp(holder.getNumericProp() + ungrouped.getNumericProp());
    // map.put(key, holder); //Edited after comments
  }
  else{
    map.put(key, ungrouped);
  }
}
return map.values().toArray(new MyObject[map.values().size()]);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without using the concatenated strings as a key?

If this was SQL (from which I'm several application layers away) it would be:

```
SELECT SUM(numericvalue) FROM sometable GROUP BY stringone, stringtwo , stringthree
```

Comment: map.put(key, holder); <-- no need for that, it was already in there

Comment: Also, you _mutate_ objects in the list as you go, is that really your intention?? I somehow doubt it!

Comment: It is not exactly that I want to mutate them, but I need the sum to be done somewhere. I figured this would use the first object it finds with the combined key as the object holding the total.

Comment: And why don't you just use an integer as a value?

Comment: Because the caller method is expecting something formatted in the way of an array of MyObjects. Now instead of having a long list of objects, they will return as a short list of objects holding the aggregated properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from some problems I see with the code, one solution would be to use (if you can afford it) [Guava's `Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) (or replicate it in your code). You'd implement an `Equivalence<MyObject>` and use a `Map<Equivalence.Wrapper<MyObject>, MyObject>` as a container; you'd make the equivalence on your three string members.

That would allow it not to break in this situation:

```
// Oops! Same key...
s1 = "foo", s2 = "bar", s3 = "baz"
s1 = "fooba", s2 = "rb", s3 = "az"
```

Also, you could use the return value of the map's `.put()` method (the old value):

```
MyObject holder = map.put(key, ungrouped);
if (holder != null)
    holder.setNumericProp(etc);
```

Comment: That's clearly more elegant than adding a separator character between them. But I'm still trying to avoid using more libraries on the project. Guava seems worth it though.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend that you use Guava ;) `Equivalence` is only one of its goodies.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking elegantly solve this you can use lambdja libraries ([**Download Here**](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar), [**Website**](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)). For example you can SUM a column with the following code ([**look at this link**](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/PerformanceAnalysis)):

```
double sum = sumFrom(select(sales, 
             having(on(Sale.class).getBuyer().isMale())
             .and( having(on(Sale.class).getSeller().isMale())))).getCost();
```

You also can group with this ([**look at this link**](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures)):

```
Group<Person> group = group(meAndMyFriends, by(on(Person.class).getAge()));
```

With this libraries you can solve your problem in few lines.